# How to reduce the column width to less than int 1 in pyqt5 table

Tags: python, pyqt5

In the code below, I'd like to achieve a visual effect of a small gap between certain columns so I have set the columns 2 and 4 to width of 1, but I would like to reduce them a lot more (reduce to have just a narrow gap), but int 1 is the lowest value I can set.  Is there way to reduce the columns width further?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class MyTable(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Narrow Columns Table')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.create_table()

    def create_table(self):
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)

        for row in range(5):
            for col in range(5):
                if col not in (1, 3):
                    item = QTableWidgetItem(f"Row {row}, Col {col}")
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row, col, item)

        # reduce width of columns 2 and 4 
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 1)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3, 1)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

def run_app():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyTable()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_app()
```

Comment: No, there is not, as widget geometries always use integer (pixel) values. Also, as already said, using dummy rows/columns to achieve this is not a good choice: 1. it wouldn't achieve the effect anyway (due to the above reason); 2. it makes access to logical indexes completely inconsistent. If you want slightly smaller *apparent* lines, you must do that *at least* by altering the `option.rect` (to ensure proper clipping) either in `paint()` or `initStyleOption()`, disabling grid lines, and draw **all of them** on your own in the `paintEvent()` override of a table widget subclass.

Comment: You make perfect sense.  I'm going to re-design it, so now will need to create a "gap" between certain columns.  I haven't found an example in python that has a table and between only select columns have a gap.  If you could point me to a link that would be oerfect  I have been looking for hours and still can't achieve it.

Comment: You cannot have gaps, as QHeaderView (on which QTableView bases geometries of items) doesn't provide that. What you can do is to adjust the `option.rect` before "sending" it to the delegate (see [`QAbstractItemView.viewOptions()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#viewOptions)) based on your needs; you have to decide if you want to adjust only the right/bottom edge of items with larger grid lines, or eventually adapt all sides, considering if an item is near the model's edges (left, top, right or bottom margins) or not.

Comment: I'll be colouring in the background cells of certain columns hence wanting the "space" between so the columns don't appear as one (I'm not using gridlines for a reason), so can  padding be applied to cells of a select column(s) to create that effect?  thanks

Comment: I just got it using option.rect- all good thanks :)